# Transorb symbol in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

A voltage supressor like the transorb diode is frequently used in circuits complementing  gas filled surge arrester. Following is an improvised symbol version using Circuitikz. The problem is that a symmetric symbol in a path requires some further tweaking!

```
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate(A) to[zzD,fill=white,*-*] (2,0)coordinate(B)  to[D, fill=white] ($(B)!0.65!(A)$) ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: It will be in the next release, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/630

Comment: I've just checked it and looks great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to[]` will always center a (single) component between two points, but you need to center two components attached together at specific locations.  In this case, it is better to use the node names.

Note that east and west do not take into account the rotation applied to the node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (A)
        (2,0) coordinate (B)
        ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) node[emptyzzdiodeshape, anchor=east] (D1a){}
          node[emptydiodeshape, anchor=east, rotate=180] (D1b){}
        (A) -- (D1a.west) (D1b.west)--(B);
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]